# How to put a scalable icon from an SVG source onto a button?

Tags: android, svg

I want to code something like this:

```
Context c = getContext();
Button b = new Button( c );
b.setBackground( new SvgDrawable( c.getAssets(), "iconImage.svg" ));
int pxWidth = Math.round( 48/*sp*/  // scaling to user preference
  * c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity/*px per sp*/ );
addView( b, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( pxWidth, WRAP_CONTENT ));
  // determines unspecified height from pxWidth and aspect ratio
```

But there's no `SvgDrawable`.  What can I substitute to get my SVG onto the button?

Please give an answer that works with any IDE.  I don't use Studio or Eclipse.

Comment: Which library you are using for svg in android?

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: @Surabhi I haven't committed to a library yet.  @Pravin My `minSdkVersion` is 21, but I could increase it.

Comment: Then how you are parsing svg file ? use some library, there are many libraries for android for using svg in android

Comment: @Surabhi Not doing it yet, just asking how.  I wrote the code example (fake code) to illustrate what I want to accomplish.

Comment: So If I am not wrong, you want to use a svg file as your button background ?

Answer (score 1):

If your minSdkVersion is 21 or greater, as you say, then you have the option to just use a `VectorDrawable` instead.  Just use one of the online converters to convert your SVG to a VectorDrawable.

Otherwise you can use a `Button` and set the background as per Surabhi's suggestion.

Or you could use an `ImageButton` and do

```
// AndroidSVG
try {
   SVG svg = SVG.getSVGFromAsset(getAssets(), "iconImage.svg");
   yourButton.setImageDrawable(new PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture()));
}
catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or if you are using svg-android, it would be:

```
// svg-android
try {
   SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(getAssets(), "iconImage.svg");
   yourButton.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
}
catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this :

```
try {
   SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(getAssets(), "iconImage.svg");
   yourButton.setBackground(svg.createPictureDrawable());
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: For AndroidSVG, you would need to use `yourButton.setBackground(new PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture()))` instead

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I eventually settled on.

### 1. Transform SVG to VectorDrawable

The preferred form of vector images is generally SVG, but the local preference on Android is `VectorDrawable`.  This raises a problem of form, and the solution I chose is a transform.

The example source below is extracted from a build script written in Nashorn JavaScript.

```js
var bufferFile = tmpDir.resolve( 'vectorDrawableBuffer.xml' ); // VD out
var inX = Build.xmlInputFactory().createXMLEventReader(
  new (Java.type('java.io.BufferedInputStream'))(
    new (Java.type('java.io.FileInputStream'))( sourceFile ))); // SVG in
var out = Files.newBufferedWriter( bufferFile );
try
{
    var factory = Build.xmlEventFactory();
    while( inX.hasNext() )
    {
        var xml = inX.next();
        if( !xml.isStartElement()
         || xml.getName().getLocalPart() != 'svg' ) continue;

        var parent;
        var parents = []; // SVG
        var _parents = []; // VectorDrawable
        function indentLine()
        {
            out.newLine();
            for( var p = parents.length; p > 0; --p ) out.append( '\t' );
        }

      // svg → vector
      // - - - - - - -
        out.append(
          '<vector xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"' );
        parents.push( parent = 'svg' );
        _parents.push( 'vector' );
        var atts;
        var att;
        var name;
        atts = xml.getAttributes();
        while( atts.hasNext() )
        {
            att = atts.next();
            name = att.getName().getLocalPart();
            if( name == 'height' )
            {
                out.append( ' a:height="' )
                  .append( att.getValue() ).append( '"' );
            }
            else if( name == 'width' )
            {
                out.append( ' a:width="' )
                  .append( att.getValue() ).append( '"' );
            }
            else if( name == 'viewBox' )
            {
              // svg[viewBox] → vector[viewportWidth, viewportHeight]
              // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                var b = att.getValue().split( ' ' );
                if( /*min-x*/b[0] != '0' || /*min-y*/b[1] != '0' )
                {
                    throw "Cannot transform, viewBox displaced from origin: "
                      + sourceFile;
                }

                out.append( ' a:viewportWidth="' )
                  .append( b[2] ).append( '"' )
                  .append( ' a:viewportHeight="' )
                  .append( b[3] ).append( '"' );
            }
        }
        out.append( '>' );
        while( inX.hasNext() )
        {
            xml = inX.next();
            if( xml.isStartElement() )
            {
                if( xml.getName().getLocalPart() != 'path' ) continue;

              // path
              // - - -
                indentLine();
                out.append( '<path' );
                atts = xml.getAttributes();
                while( atts.hasNext() )
                {
                    att = atts.next();
                    name = att.getName().getLocalPart();
                    if( name == 'd' )
                    {
                      // path[d → pathData]
                      // - - - - - - - - - -
                        out.append( ' a:pathData="' )
                          .append( att.getValue() ).append( '"' );
                    }
                    else if( name == 'fill' )
                    {
                      // path[fill → fillColor]
                      // - - - - - - - - - - - -
                        out.append( ' a:fillColor="' )
                          .append( att.getValue() ).append( '"' );
                    }
                }
                out.append( '/>' );
            }
            else if( xml.isEndElement() )
            {
                name = xml.getName().getLocalPart();
                if( name == parent )
                {
                    indentLine();
                    out.append( '</' )
                      .append( _parents.pop() ).append( '>' );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    out.close();
    inX.close();
}
```

See the [original script file](http://reluk.ca/project/waymaker/spec/build/android/Android.js) for the missing context.

### 2. Set VectorDrawable on button

```java
   final Resources res = context.getResources();
   final VectorDrawable icon;
// try
// {
//     final Class<?> c =
//       Class.forName( "android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable" );
//     final Method m = c.getMethod( "create", Resources.class, int.class );
//     icon = (VectorDrawable)m.invoke( null, res,
//       R.drawable.vector_drawable_res_id );
// }
// catch( final Exception ex ) { throw new RuntimeException( ex ); }
//// call to API-hidden method, but better inline it for production code:
   final XmlResourceParser p = res.getXml( R.drawable.vector_drawable_res_id );
   try
   {
       // Go to first element, else VectorDrawable throws XmlPullParserException
       // "Binary XML file line #-1<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0".
       for( int t = p.getEventType(); t != START_TAG; t = p.next() )
       {
           if( t == END_DOCUMENT )
           {
               throw new XmlPullParserException( "Missing start tag" );
           }
       }

       icon = new VectorDrawable();
       icon.inflate( res, p, Xml.asAttributeSet(p) );
   }
   catch( final IOException|XmlPullParserException ex )
   {
       throw new RuntimeException( ex );
   }

   button.setBackground( icon );
```

And finally, as promised:

### 3. Scale it

```java
   final float aspectRatio =
     (float)icon.getIntrinsicWidth() / icon.getIntrinsicHeight();
   final int pxWidth = Math.round( 48/*sp*/  // scaling to user preference
     * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity/*px per sp*/ );
   final int pxHeight = Math.round( pxWidth / aspectRatio );
// icon.setBounds( /*left*/0, /*top*/0, pxWidth, pxHeight );
/// needn't scale icon itself, just the button:
   addView( button, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( pxWidth, pxHeight ));
```

This isn't a simple solution looking at the code.  But I think it'll prove robust going forward (fewer unexpected pitfalls and other hidden complexities) because it uses the preferred forms on both sides: SVG on the source side, and `VectorDrawable` on the executable side.